# How gets network adapters that are members of a NIC team?

Tags: c#, networking, nic

What is the equivalent of [Get-NetLbfoTeamMember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netlbfo/get-netlbfoteammember?view=windowsserver2022-ps) in *C#* to gets network adapters that are members of a NIC team *programmatically* ?

Comment: You could probably do it with some complex WMI calls, but it might be easier to just call `Get-NetLbfoTeamMember` see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/hosting/adding-and-invoking-commands?view=powershell-7.2

Comment: @Charlieface Thank's for your suggestion